# Getting Response Headers from Apex Web Service Response with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql, oracle-apex

I have to get the response headers of my "*apex_web_service.make_rest_request*" request.

I know that it was possible with the "*UTL_HTTP*" package, as documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#BHAHDHHB

But how can I do this with "*apex_web_service*"? Is it even possible, as I can't find it in this documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI537

Thanks in advance for your answer(s)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I found it now. The answer can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI1933

There is no such thing as a "get_Header()" or something like that. You set your headers and send the request (here example code):

```
--Set Request Headers
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Authorization';
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := '[MY API TOKEN]';
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Content-Type';
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'application/json';
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).name := 'Content-Length';
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).value := '[CONTENT LENGTH IN BYTES OF REQUEST BODY]';

       l_lcResult := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url          => 'MY API URL'
                                                       ,p_http_method  => 'POST'
                                                       ,p_body         => 'REQUEST BODY IN JSON FORMAT');
```

After the request the headers "change" automatically to the response headers. You can get the response headers as followed:

```
for i in 1.. apex_web_service.g_headers.count loop
   l_vcHeaderName := apex_web_service.g_headers(i).name;
   l_vcHeaderValue := apex_web_service.g_headers(i).value;
end loop;
```

If you are searching for a specific response header (like me), you can use this:

```
 --Here we search for the header-field called 'Location'    
 for i in 1.. apex_web_service.g_headers.count loop
    l_vcHeaderName := apex_web_service.g_headers(i).name;
    l_vcHeaderValue := apex_web_service.g_headers(i).value;

    exit when l_vcHeaderName = 'Location';
 end loop;

dbms_output.put_line('Name: ' || l_vcHeaderName);
dbms_output.put_line('Value: ' || l_vcHeaderValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the HTTP response code , use:

```
apex_web_service.g_status_code
```